# How to get bitmap Contact photo uri

Tags: android, kotlin

When converting the **content://com.android.contacts/display_photo/4** to bitmap getting this error

> **Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'**

I need the user photo image which he used in the contact or default image

Below is the code

```
private fun getContactNumbers(): ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> {
    val contactsNumberMap = ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>()


    val phoneCursor: Cursor? = context.contentResolver.query(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
    )
    if (phoneCursor != null && phoneCursor.count > 0) {
        val numberIndex =
            phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)
        val nameIndex =
            phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)
        val photoIndex = phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI)
        while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
            val number: String = phoneCursor.getString(numberIndex)
            val name: String = phoneCursor.getString(nameIndex)
            val uri: String = phoneCursor.getString(photoIndex)
            //check if the map contains key or not, if not then create a new array list with number
            val objectNameNumber = ArrayList<String>()
            objectNameNumber.add(name);
            objectNameNumber.add(number)
            if(uri.isNotEmpty()) {
                val input: InputStream =
                    applicationContext.contentResolver.openInputStream(Uri.parse(uri))!!
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input)
                println(uri)
                println(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input))
                println("ByteArray-photo_stream")
            }
            if (!contactsNumberMap.contains(objectNameNumber)) {
                contactsNumberMap.add(objectNameNumber);
            }
        }
        //contact contains all the number of a particular contact
        phoneCursor.close()
    }
    return contactsNumberMap
}
```

Comment: It appears you are calling `decodeStream(input)` twice. That will not work, as the stream will already be used from the first `decodeStream()` call. Either call it once, or open a fresh stream for the second call.

Comment: I found the solution needs to 1st find the user photo via contact id and then fetch it via input stream and then convert that to bitmap or anything you want. Below is the code which needs to be changed

val contactIndex =
                phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID)
            val photoIndex =
                phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI)
    Use inputStream  and BitmapFactory to get Bitmap

Comment: val inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(
 contentResolver,  ContentUris.withAppendedId( ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactID )
                           )
                           if (inputStream != null) {
                               photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
                               val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                               photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, outputStream) val byteArray = outputStream.toByteArray()} assert(inputStream != null) inputStream!!.close()